# .Net MVC bundling/minificiation - CDN friendly file naming

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I'm working with .Net MVC bundling and minification. It does the job just fine, except you end up with a url like the following:

/bundles/AllMyScripts?v=r0sLDicvP58AIXN_mc3QdyVvVj5euZNzdsa2N1PKvb81

The project will have static files sitting in AWS Cloudfront, and by default it doesn't like querystrings. It can be changed to support this, but there is a performance penalty.

Can bundling be configured to put the token in the filename instead of the querystring? I'm also open to using something other than Web Grease.

Comment: I may be off, but I am not sure what one has to do with the other?  MVC bundling will gather the files to be bundled, bundle them and return them from the web server and not from the actual CDN.  And as far as I know, you can't store the bundles outside of your web app (if you can, that would be awesome and please correct me).  If you are wanting your compressed files to sit outside of your web app, I think you will need to manually compress your items.

Comment: @Tommy The CDN pulls from the source if it doesn't have it in cache. A request http://cdn.mysite.com/content/css/min.css would go to the CDN, and it it wasn't there, the CDN would request this from the source - which is where .net comes into play. You don't push to a CDN, it pulls from you.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are asking now, I was looking at your problem in the opposite file flow direction.  My mistake. I thought you were asking about the actual pull for the bundling process and not the CDN distributing the bundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've come up with a decent solution involving url rewriting and a custom html helper.

web.config:

```
  <rule name="BundlingRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^content/min/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
      <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="content/min/{R:1}?v={R:2}" />
  </rule>
```

helper:

```
public static IHtmlString RenderCdnCss(this HtmlHelper helper, params string[] paths)
{
    if (BundleTable.EnableOptimizations)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Uri baseUri = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;

        foreach (string s in paths) {
            Uri uri = new Uri(baseUri, BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl(s));
            sb.AppendFormat("<link href=\"{0}\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/>", uri.PathAndQuery.Replace("?v=", "/"));                    
        }
        return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
    return Styles.Render(paths);
}
```

The helper translates the bundled url into something more CDN friendly. For example:

/content/min/css?v=3GWBEyScjC610oPQm0JVybboQ_EmX3StAuCZjd_B7bE1

becomes

/content/min/css/3GWBEyScjC610oPQm0JVybboQ_EmX3StAuCZjd_B7bE1

The url rewrite (IIS Url Rewrite 2.0) looks for a url inside content/min/{some folder}/{some token} and rewrites it to content/min/{some folder}?v={some token} (what the path looks by default)

So, the bundler is none the wiser, and the path becomes CDN friendly. In my case I will also prepend the cdn url to the front of the url, but that's not included above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MapRoute` and a `Controller` to rewrite the bundle URL to be CDN friendly.

Instead of 
`/bundles/AllMyScripts?v=r0sLDicvP58AIXN_mc3QdyVvVj5euZNzdsa2N1PKvb81` you will have `CDN_Bundle/bundles/AllMyScripts/r0sLDicvP58AIXN_mc3QdyVvVj5euZNzdsa2N1PKvb81`.

RouteMap:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CDN_Bundle",
            url: "CDN_Bundle/{*virtualPath}",
            defaults: new { controller = "CDN_Bundle", action = "Index" }
```

Action:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string virtualPath)
    {
        virtualPath = virtualPath.Trim('/');
        int lastSlash = virtualPath.LastIndexOf("/");
        string hashCode = virtualPath.Substring(lastSlash + 1, virtualPath.Length - lastSlash -1 );
        virtualPath = virtualPath.Substring(0, virtualPath.LastIndexOf("/"));

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", Request.UserAgent);
        Stream data = webClient.OpenRead(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Path.Combine(Request.ApplicationPath, virtualPath) + "?v=" + hashCode);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();

        return Content(content);
    }
```

and use this instead of `Scripts.Render`

```
         <script src="/cdn_bundle@(System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/AllMyScripts").Replace("?v=","/"))"></script>
```

Comment: It's a fine idea, but there must be a more efficient way of doing this!

Comment: @ScottE The effective way is minifying the scripts manually by WG and put them on the AWS CloudFront, then bundle them and set `UseCdn` property of the bundle to true. See [Amazon CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html), See Using a CDN in [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: I like that suggestion better. Could you explain that suggestion in more detail?

Comment: @ScottE There are two link in my previous comment about using `UseCdn' property and how to add static file to Amazon CloudFront.But I cannot understand why you think my approach is not effective. As mentioned in your comment CDN only request the object if it hadn't it in their cache. Therefore the action is called once and there is no performance issue here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Kambiz, but I went a bit of a different direction. I did use System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl, however. Also, that's a fair point about the CDN - once cached the routine won't get hit until it's changed / stale.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i've picked up what your after correctly but..

When you define bundles in BundelConfig there is a parameter of ScriptBundle called CdnPath that can be set for each bundel to a CDN location.

In RegisterBundles

```
Dim bundel As New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myfoo")
bundel.CdnPath = "http://foo.com/foo.js"

bundles.UseCdn = True
```